# threading using simple c

Tags: multithreading

i would like to implement a thread framework using simple c and timers....can anyone help me out...by providing some sample libraries or material...

Comment: What do you mean by "implement a thread framework"? What do you mean by "simple c"?

Comment: Sure you need threads? Maybe forking a process will do the work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help to have a look at [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/), a POSIX standard for threads:

> Pthreads are defined as a set of C language programming types and procedure calls, implemented with a pthread.h header/include file and a thread library - though this library may be part of another library, such as libc, in some implementations.